# How to profile remote ubuntu JVM using VisualVM?

Tags: java, ubuntu, profiling, visualvm

I am trying to profile remote JVM using VisualVM. I have a remote production ubuntu machine on which my Java application is running and that's what I need to profile. I was following this [tutorial](http://www.codefactorycr.com/java-visualvm-to-profile-a-remote-server.html) to profile a remote server.

I started `jstatd` on my ubuntu production machine like this -

```
root@productionMachineA:/home/david# /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=permissions.txt -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=100.41.76.19 -J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Here `100.41.76.19` is the IP Address of my production ubuntu machine. After starting `jstatd` on the ubunut machine, I did -

```
netstat -nlp | grep jstatd
```

And I can see this -

```
root@productionMachineA:~$ netstat -nlp | grep jstatd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1099            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32103/jstatd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60707           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32103/jstatd
```

which looks to me `jstatd` is running fine I guess. Now I opened `VisualVM` on my desktop, right click on Remote and select Add Remote Host, and finally type the IP address of the production machineA. And afterwards I don't see anything happening on VisualVM which makes me think something is wrong for sure.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and what are the things I should try on? If anyone can provide steps by steps what I am supposed to do then it will be of great help.

**Update:-**

After adding port `1099` on my remote connection.

I got this error. Cannot connect to `100.41.76.19` using `service:jmx:rmi.....`

From my local desktop, I tried telnet on remote machine on port 1099 and this is what I got -

```
david@localDesktop ~
$ telnet 100.41.76.19 1099

david@localDesktop ~
$
```

Comment: Right click on that host and add the jstad details like hostname and portno.

Comment: I added that along with my username and password and after that I got this error `Cannot connect to 100.41.76.19 using service:jmx:rmi.....`

Comment: Is the port number correct??  Also make sure there us no firewall in your production server blocking connections on that port.

Comment: I added 1099 port number. How do I check that firewall issues? If you can provide some steps, I can execute those to see what's happening?

Comment: Try telnet from your local machine on that port. telnet ipaddress port no.

Comment: From my local machine I did `david@localDesktop ~
$ telnet 100.41.76.19 1099

david@localDesktop ~
$` and nothing got on my console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54961/discussion-between-user2809564-and-shashank-kadne).